# Replace wire to 60A subpanel

Tags: electrical, garage, subpanel

Short Version: Anything wrong with running 6/3 NM in a joist well to a junction box that leads out to a 60A garage subpanel?

Longer Version:
I'm thinking of finishing a room in my basement.  It has a mess of wires that will need to be cleaned up and enclosed in the ceiling.  This includes an 1.5" galvanized conduit with wires for my 60A detached garage subpanel.  These wires could be secured between floor joists all the way from the main panel to just before the junction box inside the house leading to the garage.  I'd like to remove that conduit (it's very in the way for finishing), ditch the old huge gauge individual wires, and replace that whole section with 6/3 NM-B stapled inside the joist well.  Any issues with that?  The current setup only has 3 wires from the main to the garage- I don't see any ground wire.

The first pic is the part of the conduit (and to the left across the basement) I'd like to replace with NM-B.  The second is the junction box leading to the garage- in from the main on the left, down to the buried conduit on the bottom.  The other smaller wires coming into the box would be removed. The third pic (actually 3 pics) follows the conduit back to the main.  In 3a the conduit's not terribly in the way, but it would be nice to lose that (yet another) junction box that serves no purpose, and free up a little room in the utility room.  In 3b is the place I really need the room- all those wires and pipes have to get pushed flush up against the joists and boxed in with wood to accommodate the low ceiling.  3c shows the main.  The close part of that room will be finished, so all those wires need to be moved back into the joist well above the wall, as the arrows show.

[image: section to remove]

[image: junction box]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A picture or diagram of what you're planning might help us better understand what you're describing.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @DanielGriscom.  I edited my post to add pics and hopefully make it clearer.  If there's anything else I can do please let me know.

Comment: Good stuff: thanks. Let's see if one of our pros can weigh in.

Comment: Can you post a photo showing the overall conduit run through the space you're finishing out? I'm trying to reckon what your options actually are here, as swapping the run out for NM gives up quite a bit of flexibility and expandability....

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, more pics added of the run.  This wire serves one purpose (the garage 60A) so I don't know what expandability I'd be losing.  I'm trying to add literal physical flexibility and downsizing (cross section, not load).

Comment: @Eric -- let me put it this way: that conduit could handle a 200A(!!!) feeder to your garage if you really wanted it to.

Comment: Why not just put a drop ceiling in and leave existing infrastructure alone? Unless doing so would give severely limited ceiling height, I don't know why you'd want to do this. Or alternatively, just make a chase around all of this electrical. (?)

Comment: "I don't know what expandability I'd be losing" **one never does...**

Comment: @peinal it's obvious that this *previously was* finished space, with a fully-boxed-in utility trunk. OP has removed that clothing with an eye toward relocating or eliminating those utilities to remove the bump altogether.

Comment: @Eric -- another thing: I take it the smaller wires on the bottom left of the pull box are the ones you're removing? What do they currently feed, even?

Comment: @peinal The ceiling height is severely limited, yes. The steel beam across that bedroom door clears my head by 1".  I want all this electrical to take as little space as possible so as to make as small a bump as I can.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It's just a 4' whip with a receptacle on the end, which I have no need for in the laundry room (used to be a garage, that's probably why it's there).

Comment: @Eric -- would reworking the conduit run (vs. replacing it with NM) be an option? How deep are the joists, for that matter?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I guess I'm not understanding why this is generating so much trepidation here.  Why do people seem to be considering the current setup so superior to NM?  Or am I misreading?  I understand I'd be losing the ability to use a 200A feeder- is that the whole thing?  Reworking the conduit would be technically possible, but a ton of work compared to NM (due to close quarters, drilling, etc.).

Comment: @Eric -- conduit lets you, or the next person down the road, add more wires, or upgrade the run to bigger wires, simply by pulling them through the conduit (instead of having to rip cables out of walls).

Comment: The reason you don't see a ground wire is that your hand is _touching_ it in the first pic. The metal conduit is used as the ground. No sense pulling an expensive wire through expensive metal conduit when you're legally allowed to use the conduit as the _safety_ ground (i.e. it's not normally current carrying - only for the second or so in a non-normal situation before the breaker trips.)

Comment: Thanks for all the info everyone.  We ended up selling the house before I could come up with a perfect solution, so I left the conduit in place and chased around it as best I could after pushing it up against the joists in order to get the basement finished quickly.  Lots of good discussion and info here- sad to see the question ended up with a negative score!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a tap, this means there is no disconnect or circuit breaker so the conduit would be required. If this is the case.